# 5V to 3.3V what is wrong on my schematic?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, dc-dc-converter, step-down

I made a schematic based on the SY8089A1AAC([Datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/2001171834_Silergy-Corp-SY8089A1AAC_C479074.pdf))

My schematic(I tried with and without C8):
[image]

I soldered everything but the output is 0V(0.04V to be precise)

What is so wrong ?

It is part of a bigger PCB which does not have any other components soldered at the moment. Only the ESP32 and the DC/DC circuit.
Power to the DC/DC circuit is provided with 2 little cables soldered temporary on the pcb from USB +5V and GND (measured the voltage and it is 5V..)
[image]

I tried to "copy" the schematic of LilyGo which is based on SY8089AAAC([datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1809042027_Silergy-Corp-SY8089AAAC_C78988.pdf))
[image]

Comment: Can you show your PCB (or whatever it is that you soldered)

Comment: Measure voltages on different points of your soldered circuit. It could be a workmanship problem.

Comment: @BeB00 edited the original post.

Comment: L looks too puny. What’s the DCR? <-30 mOhm?

Comment: The Enable pin must be pulled High for the regulator to work - why are you holding it at half-supply?

Comment: @PeterBennett according to the datasheet, 1.2V is considered 'high' for the EN pin.

Comment: @brhans: As I read the datasheet, the minimum High threshold for Enable is 1.5 volts, but it can apparently be connected directly to +5V, so there is no need for the voltage divider. (and I see no mention of Enable pin current.  With the 100K resistors in the divider, it wouldn't take much Enable pin current to change the divider voltage.)

Comment: Did you check the voltage at 1 & 4?

Answer (score 3):

The smallest acceptable size in a 2A regulator @ 1 MHz if using 2.2uH is 4.8mm square to get 30 mOhm max with an L/R ratio of ~ 73 us and a Q<0.1 with fo of 16kHz @ 44uF and probably unstable. But yours is far too lossy and underdamped and too puny.

Remove 1 (22uF) cap also and review phase compensation design for breakpoint and phase margin.  There is a problem with 5kHz phase lead compensation and an underdamped resonant frequency of 16 kHz.

This does not exclude that you may have mechanical soldering issues and the onus is on you to identify all pin voltages to verify the function of that port and all connected parts to debug in your question.

You would have been better off with 1uH 10mOhm and 10uF <1 mOhm but the datasheet only hints at that! ‘☆’ means recommended for most applications.

### Rule of Thumb

Never deviate one little bit from suggested layout and components in SMPS unless you know what you are doing!  (Especially but not only at >1MHz)

Comment: thanks for your reply. what makes it lossy, underdamped ,puny? the soldering isn't good?

Comment: Search DCR , L  here  DCR is the DC resistance of the coil which cannot store energy only lose some., but I think you have  mechanical problem and a debugging problem with no voltages marked up on your schematic  Have you considered a short circuit?

Comment: you were right about the mechanical problem. i soldered an other board and it works. its either a PCB issue or some short circuit..

Comment: Your efficiency will suffer with a puny L. Even though that schematic shows 100mOhm, the datasheet recommends 30mOhm

Comment: are you referring to the schematic that i "copied" or to the schematic that i made? for L i choosed a "random" 2.2uH inductor(https://www.murata.com/en-global/products/productdetail?partno=DFE252010F-2R2M%23 )

Comment: I checked now me inductor and it has Max. of DC resistance 0.097ohm.. thats the DCR you were talking about? I guess i shall find one with 30

Comment: Then compare max power efficiency and performance to step loads + & -. For over/undershoot and report back in question. Getting a lower DCR package to fit this layout might not be easy or possible, which is why a smaller L& C (low ESR) was suggested as ideal for most designs, depending on ripple and regulation error and efficiency trade offs.